# PDF content search doesn't work in "Find an item" search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, pdf, crawl

I am creating list with numerous custom columns. One of the columns is multiple lines of text and I use it to upload some pdf files (I need to have more than one document in one item). When i try to search in the list search box "Find an item":
[image: Find an item search box]

for some words from PDF files that I updated there is no result. But if i try same thing from "Search this site" I get results so I presume it is not crawl or search issue. What am I doing wrong?

All the best

Comment: I am confused, you say you are putting the PDF into the Multiple Lines of Text field? Or are you just using the attachment to the list item? Or is this a document library?

Comment: Yes, I am putting PDF files in Multiple Lines of Text field (there is upload option there, and then I can see my files in view as well I see link to all my files). This is custom list not document library.